# is it possible to find out the Azure Table's creation date?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have some code that creates azure Table, is it possible to somehow retrieve the creation date of an Azure table (like I can do with sql table)? So I can delete old tables easily (otherwise I am thinking of putting creation time in Azure table name).

By looking at `CloudTable` class, seems we don't have any attributes I can use. Is there any other way?

Comment: Free to ask any further question. Or could you accept the suggestion if it does help?

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, there's no related property on SDK. Creation time is not recorded or exposed by existing Storage APIs.

We are able to use [Storage logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enabling-storage-logging-and-accessing-log-data#FindingyourStorageLogginglogdata) to achieve our goal. In `$log` blob container, check table related blobs, search for `CreateTable` event, corresponding tableName and time).

But apparently it costs much more than simply adding time in the table name. Or we could just create a new table to record creation time.